# How to dispatch a command on ATOM?

Tags: dom, atom-editor, dom-events

I want to know how to dispatch an command on ATOM.

I tried with this **code**:

```coffee
  activate: (state) ->
    @subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable    
    @subscriptions.add atom.commands.add "atom-workspace",
      "activate-killer-instinct-mode:test-command": =>
        console.log "Hello, I'm your commands"
        @error = false

    target = "atom-workspace"
    commandName = "activate-killer-instinct-mode:test-command"

    atom.commands.dispatch target, commandName #Here is the error

    console.log "The command " + commandName + " got dispatched" if not @error
    console.error "The command " + commandName + " didn't get dispatched" if @error
```

I got this **output**:

```
The command activate-killer-instinct-mode:test-command didn't get dispatched
```

I read the [documentation](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.19.1/CommandRegistry#instance-dispatch).

> ::dispatch(target, commandName)
>
> ```
>   ╭─────────────╥─────────────────────────────────────────╮
>   │  Argument   ║  Description                            │
>   ╞═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╡
>   │   target    ║ The DOM node at which to start bubbling │
>   |             ║ the command event.                      │
>   ╞═════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╡
>   │ commandName ║ String indicating the name of the       │
>   |             ║ command to dispatch.                    |
>   └─────────────╨─────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

I think the error is in the target, I don't know how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe that the error lies in you passing a string as target instead of a nodeElement itself (an object, not a string). Try getting the target as in `target = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()`, or whatever works for you.

Comment: I solve the issue a long time ego. Soon I will write the solution.